# Retrieve and insert to cloud database using C# winforms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, phpmyadmin, cloud

I have joined a free cloud web hosting service. I have created a database on it using PHPMyAdmin.

I have written the following piece of code that should allow me to extract the info stored in the table of the database onto a datagridview.

```
private void connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        username = "name";
        password = "pass";

       
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id='" + username + "';database=dbname;password='" + password_mysql + "'"))
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table_1", connection);
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I click the connect button I get the following error:
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

What I want to do is to set up a database on the cloud and then use my Winforms application to display the contents of the database table. I would also like to insert, update, and delete stuff in the table using the WinForms application.

Can someone assist me?

**N.B.
The connection works well when using MySQL on my local machine. However when I change the values to match my cloud-based database on PHPMyAdmin then I cannot access it.**

Comment: Try removing the single quotes in the password.  See following for the connection string : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: @jdweng Now getting "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Comment: How did you solve your problem?